# Mongoose TypeError Invalid schema configuration

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

have I done something wrong in the schema?

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;


const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    username: {
      name: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
      trim: true,
      minlength: 3
    },
  }, 
  {
    timestamps: true
  }
);

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

The error I get

```
throw new TypeError(`Invalid schema configuration: \`${name}\` is 
not ` + ^ TypeError: Invalid schema configuration: `True` is not a valid type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `name` is not valid attribute in mongoose schemas. Try to replace `name` by `type` and correct the `minlength` typo to `minLength`:

```
const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    username: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
      trim: true,
      minLength: 3
    },
  }, 
  {
    timestamps: true
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the schema to below

```
  const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    username: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
      trim: true,
      minlength: 3
    },
  }, 
  {
    timestamps: true
  }
);
```

instead of 'name' just use 'type'

For further reference follow this link https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html